# What does std::move do when called on a function?

Tags: c++, stdmove

I'm working on making some changes to a piece of code, and have a doubt in understanding the behavior of std::move in below case:

```cpp
struct Timer {
   Timer (boost::asio::io_service& ios) : timer_{ios} {}
   boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
};

struct TimerContext {
   void *ctxt_;
};

class A {
   std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)>    callback_;
   boost::asio::io_service                              ios_;
};
```

A's constructor:

```cpp
A::A (std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> cb) : callback_{std::move(cb)}
{
}
```

The callback function definition:

```cpp
void
customCallback (Timer *timer, const TimerContext& ctxt) {
...
}
```

In `main()`,

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

    A *a = new A{customCallback};

}
```

My doubt is for this line:
`A::A (std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> cb) : callback_{std::move(cb)}`

Class A is getting instantiated in a loop, and the **same** `customCallback` function is getting moved to the custom constructor for each new object.

Will the first std::move not make callback function unusable for next call? As I understood, if you use `std::move(t)`, then `t` cannot be used again in that scope.

I'm confused what is happening internally here for all 5 calls to `std::move(cb)` on the same function in `new A`. Is this the right way to do how it is implemented?

Comment: It's worth noting that since your std::function wraps a plain function pointer it contains no allocated memory pointers, and therefore the std::move will not be any more efficient than a regular copy operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at A's constructor:

```
A::A (std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> cb)
```

The function, `cb` is being passed **by value**.  That means a copy of the function has already occurred from when it was invoked via new:

```
A *a = new A{customCallback};
```

The `std::move` in the constructor initializer list exists to avoid a redundant copy into the member variable.  The original function defined by the caller who invoked `new A` remains unmoved.  This is preferred because copying a `std::function` variable can be expensive. (`sizeof(cb)` - might be way bigger than you expected).

An alternative implementation: The function could have been passed as a const reference and allow the copy to occur in the constructor itself:

```
A::A (const std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)>& cb) : callback_{cb}
```

Comment: does the alternative implementation suggested by you have any benefit over the one used in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor `A::A (std::function<void(Timer *, const TimerContext&)> cb)` takes its parameter *by value*, i.e. `customCallback` is first *copied* into `cb`, then moved from that copy into `callback_`.

So every time the constructor is called, the copy is moved from, not the original `customCallback` object.

Also, you should avoid using raw calls to `new` and prefer smart pointers instead to avoid memory leaks, but that was not the question at hand here :-)